# How to scale down a list of integers

Tags: algorithms, big-list, data-analysis

I have a list, that can be of various lengths (less than 100 or more than 1.800.000) and I need to
"shrink down" the list to 800 values.

I have tried taking a value for every step, where a step is the list length / 800. And it is the closest I can get to. I have tried taking the average value of the n surrounding of step with various n, but I can't get a waveform that satisfies me.

I know image compression work by taking an average of surrounding pixels, and I am trying to do the same with a list of values. I need to preserve the global aspect, but also the highest and lowest spikes.

Comment: Without knowing what information you are interested in it is hard to make a recommendation.  You mention wanting the max and min.  How about keeping just some quantile levels?  That gives a pretty good feel for the distribution.  When you say waveform it suggests doing an FFT and keeping the most significant terms.  What are you looking for?

Comment: @RossMillikan  I have values ranging from 0 to 200 and a screen of 800 points horizontally. On compter, I have an audio sample, and I can draw a waveform. What I want to do is get all the values (0 10 20 22 24 100 199 ...) and display them on an 800 screen. 
That's why I need the 'global aspect' to be the same and 'spikes'. Let's say 8000 points, I can't take 1 in 10 because it skips 9 values. Not precise enough. I tried the average of n percent before, let's say the average of (1 2,3 ), skip 8, the average  of (9 10 11) .... Then draw all the averages. But the wave is too flat.

Comment: You can stream it to the display and show all the data.  You can just show a segment if the waveform doesn't change with time.  I don't understand why skipping values is not precise enough.  I suggested FFT because it keeps frequency content and can suppress noise.  Math can do a lot of things but it can't tell you what you want.  You have to decide that.